# Divide timespan by 2?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime, xml-parsing

I have two times, and their values are picked up from a XML from web.

```
XElement xmlWdata = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

string SunRise = xmlWdata.Element("sun").Attribute("rise").Value;
string SunSet = xmlWdata.Element("sun").Attribute("set").Value;

DateTime sunrise = Convert.ToDateTime(SunRise.Remove(0,11));
DateTime sunset = Convert.ToDateTime(SunSet.Remove(0, 11));
```

This gives med the time: 04:28 for sunrise, and 22:00 for sunset.
How to then do a calculation where i take:

**`(sunrise + (sunset-sunrise)/2)`**

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
TimeSpan span = sunset-sunrise;
TimeSpan half = new TimeSpan(span.Ticks / 2);
DateTime result = sunrise + half;
```

It can be written in one line if you want.

Answer (score 2):

`TimeSpan sunnyTime = TimeSpan.FromTick(sunrise.Ticks + (sunset.Ticks - sunrise.Ticks) / 2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
TimeSpan halfTimeSpan = timeSpan.Divide(2);
```